Evaluation boundary condition for mean capture time equation leads to 1/sin(x) at $\pi$
The so called 'mean capture time equation' reads
$\nabla^2 W + \frac{1}{D} = 0$
with boundary conditions $W(\theta_C)=0$ and $W'(\theta)=0$. (Linderman et al. Toward Quantifying the Activation of Helper T Lymphocytes by Antigen Presenting Cells. Lectures on Mathematics in the Life Sciences Volume 24, 1994)
$W$ is the mean time for a molecule at some initial position on a sphere to reach an absorbing boundary, which in spherical coordinates for the special case with fixed radius, $R$, reads
$\frac{1}{R^2 \sin(\theta)} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} (\sin(\theta) \frac{\partial W}{\partial \theta}) + \frac{1}{R^2 \sin^2(\theta)} \frac{\partial^2 W}{\partial^2\phi}+\frac{1}{D} =0$.
$D$ is the diffusion coefficient for a receptor in the cell membrane.
(The figure illustrates the 'contact' area, green arc defined by critical angle $\theta_C$, when Th cell encounters and APC cell. Both the T cell receptor, TCR, and MHC-ag complex can diffuse in the membrane in and out the contact area, also called synapse. Rate constants for the diffusion of molecules into and out of the contact area, which is the reason behind this analysis, can be estimated by solving the above mean capture time as described in Linderman et al. 1994. Also described in Berg's 'Random Walks in Biology'.)

Separation of variables, $W = T(\theta) S(\phi)$,  leads to an ODE for the azimuthal component
$\frac{1}{R^2} \frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial^2 \phi}=0$ with solution $S(\phi)=C_1\phi + C_2$.
The ODE for the polar component reads
$\frac{1}{R^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} (\sin(\theta) \frac{\partial T}{\partial \theta}) + \frac{\sin(\theta)}{D} =0$ which then can be written in the following form
$\sin(\theta) T''(\theta) + \cos(\theta) T'(\theta) + \sin(\theta)\frac{R^2}{D}=0$.
The ODE for $T$ can be solved using integration factor method leading to equation
$T'(\theta) = \frac{R^2}{D} \cot(\theta) + \frac{C_3}{\sin(\theta)}$
Integration leads to (using Wolfram's Alpha)
$T(\theta) = \frac{R^2 \log(\sin(\theta))}{D} - \log(\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})) C_3 + \log(\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})) C_3 + C_4$.
Evaluating $T(\theta_C)=0$ gives
$\frac{R^2 \log(\sin(\theta_C))}{D} - \log(\cos(\frac{\theta_C}{2})) C_3 + \log(\sin(\frac{\theta_C}{2})) C_3 + C_4 =0$
Evaluating $T'(\pi)=0$ gives
$\frac{R^2}{D} \cot(\theta) + \frac{C_3}{\sin(\theta)} = 0$
whith both terms undefined at $\pi$.
Any idea what to do next?
Moreover, how one wowld estimate the two other constants, $C_1$ and $C_2$? Two boundary conditions are given but there are four constants.
Any comments would be very appreciated!

$S(\phi)$ must be $2\pi$-periodic in $\phi$ to yield a sensible solution on a sphere. That means that if $S(\phi) = C_1 \phi + C_2$, then we must have $C_1 = 0$. This also makes sense since your boundary conditions and your whole problem appear to be symmetric in $\phi$, i.e. no value of $\phi$ is distinguishable from any other value.

I'm a little confused about your boundary conditions. Did you mean to write $W'(\theta_C) = 0$? What is $\theta_C$? Just a fixed parameter?

If you want $T'(\pi) = 0$, then the $\lim_{\theta\rightarrow\pi} T'(\theta) = 0$ only when $C_3 = R^2/D$.

@JohnBarber yes, $\theta_C$ is fixed, determined by the radii of these two cells

@JohnBarber could you explain the $\lim_{\theta \rightarrow \pi}T'(\theta)=0$ with $C_3=R^2/D$? As I see it only in the denominator you get $0$, so the d'Hospital does not apply.

When $C_3 = R^2/D$, you have $T'(\theta) = (R^2/D)\frac{\cos\theta + 1}{\sin\theta}$. This quantity is well-behaved as $\theta\rightarrow\pi$. In fact, it goes to $0$. You can graph it and see. Therefore this is the only value of $C_3$ that makes any sense given the boundary conditions of this problem.

You should find that the overall solution to this problem is $W(\theta, \phi) = 2C_2\frac{R^2}{D}\log\left[\frac{\sin(\theta/2)}{\sin(\theta_C/2)}\right]$. There is not enough information given to determine the value of $C_2$.
